# Cracking a binary file format if I have the contents of one of these files

Tags: binary, cracking

I have about 300 measurements (each stored in a dat file) that I would like to read using MATLAB or Python. The files can be exported to text or csv using a proprietary program, but this has to be done one by one.

**The question is:** what would be the best approach to crack the format of the binary file using the known content from the exported file?

Not sure if this makes any difference to make the cracking easier, but the files are just two columns of (900k) numbers, and from the dat files' size (1,800,668 bytes), it appears as if each number is 16 bits (float) and there is some other information (possible the header).

I tried using HEX-Editor, but wasn't able to pick up any trends from there.

Lastly, I want to make sure to specify that these are measurements I made and the data in them belongs to me. I am not trying to obtain data that I am not supposed to.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Reading up a little more I realized that there my be some kind of compression going on. When you look at the data in StreamWare, it gives 7 decimal places, leading me to believe that it is a single precision value (4 bytes). However, the size of the files suggests that each value only takes 2 bytes.

Comment: What application created the binary files?

Comment: StreamWare. It is a program use for hot-wire anemometry.

Comment: With compression or some kind of system of deltas + key frames the first thing I'd do is ask StreamWare if they document the format.  If you're lucky they might even have a SDK for decoding.  If not, I'd ask them about adding export commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it a little more, I finally figured it out. This is very specific, but just in case another Dantec StreamWare user runs into the same problem, it could save him/her a little time.

First, the data is actually only a single vector. The time column is calculated from the length of the recorded signal and the sampling frequency. That information is probably in the header (but I wasn't able to crack that portion).

To obtain the values in MATLAB, I skipped the header bytes using `fseek(fid, 668, 'bof')`, then I read the data as uint16 using `fread(fid, 900000, 'uint16')`. This gives you integers.

To get the float value, all you have to do is divide by 2^16 (it's a 16 bit resolution system) and multiply by ten. I assume the factor of ten depends on the range of your data acquisition system.

I hope this helps.